# Prolog: first steps

Tags: prolog

I'm beginner of prolog and I started to write this simple program

```
case(a):-case(b),case(c).
case(b):-case(d),case(e).
case(d).
case(d):-case(c).
case(d):-case(e).
```

If I ask to prolog : ?-case(a) , it returns FALSE. Shouldn't it return TRUE?

Comment: at first glance, you're missing two facts `case(c).` and `case(e).`

Comment: `case(a) :- case(b), case(c).` says that *`case(a)` is true if `case(b)` is true and `case(c)` is true*. However, neither `case(b)` nor `case(c)` are provable, so `case(a)` fails.

Comment: @lurker: I believe this helped the OP solve their problem; you could post it as an answer perhaps?